# What is the usage of this code in CancelToken.js for the source code of Axios

Tags: javascript, axios, promise

Recently I was learning the source code of Axios(https://github.com/axios/axios).

However, in `CancelToken.js`, there is a part of code that I don't understand.

```js
    // eslint-disable-next-line func-names
    this.promise.then = onfulfilled => {
      let _resolve;
      // eslint-disable-next-line func-names
      const promise = new Promise(resolve => {
        token.subscribe(resolve);
        _resolve = resolve;
      }).then(onfulfilled);

      promise.cancel = function reject() {
        token.unsubscribe(_resolve);
      };

      return promise;
    };
```

Originally, I think it is used to overwrite the `then` method of `this.promise`. And then, I write a demo to verify my idea.

```js
        let resolve
        let p = new Promise((res, rej) => resolve = res)
        p.then(val => {
          console.log('In p.then ', val)
        })
        p.then = onFulfill => {
          console.log('I am here')
          const promise = new Promise(resolve => {
            resolve(2)
          }).then(onFulfill)
          return promise
        }
        console.log(p.then)
        resolve(1)
```

If as what I expected, 'I am here' should be print. However, it can't print 'I am here'. So I don't understand the usage of `this.promise.then = onFulfilled => ...` in Axios source code.

Can anyone help me! THX!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Overwriting the method

You are correct, this does overwrite the `then` method of this `Promise` instance; the important thing here is *when* that happens.

If you consider this (extremely poor) resolve-only `Promise` implementation:

```
class Future {                                                                                                      
  constructor(executor) {                                                                                             
    this._state = 'pending';                                                                                          
                                                                                                                      
    executor(result => {                                                                                              
      if (this._state !== 'pending') {                                                                                
        return;                                                                                                       
      }                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                      
      this._state = 'fulfilled';                                                                                      
      if (!this._onFulfilled) {                                                                          
        return;                                                                                                       
      }                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                      
      this._onFulfilled(result);                                                                                      
    });                                                                                                               
  }                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                      
  then(onFulfilled) {                                                                                                 
    this._onFulfilled = onFulfilled;                                                                                  
  }                                                                                                                   
}
```

you can see that, if called like so:

```
const future = new Future(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
future.then(() => console.log('fulfilled'));
future.then = console.log;
future.then('and then?');
```

reassigning `then` will leave the internal value of `_onFulfilled` untouched, and any subsequent calls to `future.then` will use the modified method.

### In Axios?

In the Axios code, this appears to be used to allow using the `CancelToken` instance in two ways:

- as an object owning a [`thenable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#thenables), where the modified `then` appends the `onFufilled` handler to the internal `_listeners` array and returns a `Promise`, or
- as a rough [`Observable`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/class/Observable), pushing the handler directly onto the `_listeners` array

So, mocking this up using the following setup:

```
let resolve;                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                      
const future = new Promise(res => resolve = res)                                                                       
                                                                                                                      
const listeners = [];                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                      
future.then(val => {                                                                                                  
  for (const listener of listeners) {                                                                                 
    listener(val);                                                                                                    
  }                                                                                                                   
});

future.then = onFulfilled => new Promise(resolve => {                                                                  
  listeners.push(resolve);                                                                                            
}).then(onFulfilled);
```

the output of this:

```
for (let index = 0; index < 10; index++) {                                                                            
  future.then(val => console.log(`${index}: ${val}`));                                                                
}
```

is equivalent to that of this:

```
for (let index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
  listeners.push(val => console.log(`${index}: ${val}`));
}
```

when kicked off with:

```
resolve(1);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it is really helpful and based on your answer I think I catch something!

It seems that by overwriting ```then``` method, Axios gives us more ways to add a function to ```tokens._listeners```. 

However, I think I check Axios official document carefully, and they give no explanation and examples to use this way to add function to ```tokens._listeners```. Do you know how to use this overwrite ```then``` method when we use Axios.

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: If your question is _how_ to use `CancelToken`, then they document it pretty well [here](https://github.com/axios/axios#canceltoken-deprecated) (and also note that it's deprecated and not to use). If you want to know how to use the `subscribe` method, it operates pretty much like `Observable`, but my takeaway from reading the code is that it is used internally, in [the](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/v1.x/lib/adapters/http.js#L161) [adapters](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/v1.x/lib/adapters/http.js#L123) so that they can be notified when the user cancels a request ✌

Comment: Thanks for your response!  Certainly I know how to use ```CancelToken```lol. If we use ```CancelToken``` by the method record in the official document, what Axios do is by using ```subscribe``` function push the ```onCancel``` function to the ```tokens._listeners```. And in this way, the modified ```then``` method will not be called. So my question is when and how will this modified ```then``` method be called?

Comment: Ah I see! Going over the git history, it looks like uses of `CancelToken.promise.then` were removed as part of [PR 3305](https://github.com/axios/axios/pull/3305), to address a memory leak.